# Betti number of a complex manifold which is a flat family

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fibration, betti-numbers

In practice, we wish to know if the topology of the base manifold and that of general fibres can somewhat "control" the topology of the total space.

Precisely, let $\pi: X\to B$ be a flat morphism between projective complex manifolds where the base space $B$ and fibres are supposed to be connected. By Sard's theorem, one knows that general fibres of $\pi$ are smooth, and diffeomorphic to each other by Ehressmann's theorem.

On knowing the Betti numbers of the base space $B$ and those of a general fibre $F$, does one have something controlling the Betti numbers of the total space $X$ ?

P.S. In the case where $\pi: X\to B$ is furthermore supposed to be smooth (submersive), by Ehressmann's theorem, $\pi$ is in fact a topological fibration. So one may utilise things like Leray-Serre's spectral sequence to control the Betti numbers of $X$. For example, in the case when $B$ is simply-connected, one has
$$b_k(X)\leq \sum_{p+q=k}b_p(F)b_q(B),$$
where $b_i$ signifies the Betti numbers.

Comment: In the case that $\pi$ is a fibration, I think you actually have more; Leray-Serre specializes to the Leray-Hirsch theorem, which says that the cohomology of $X$ can be computed as a tensor product of the cohomologies of the base and the model fiber. If $\pi$ actually has singular fibers, then you may be out of luck depending on what you actually know, and indeed you may find yourself "going backwards":...

Comment: ...for instance, when you have a general pencil of degree $d$ plane curves, the blow up of its base locus produces a family whose general fiber is a smooth genus $g=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$ curve. However, the typical analysis one carries out is that one knows the Euler characteristic of the total space ($X$ being $\mathbb{CP}^2$ blown up at $d^2$ points, so $\chi(X) = 3 + d^2$) and the base ($\chi(\mathbb P^1)=2$), so by comparing one can get a good idea of what the singular locus looks like (at least assuming the singular fibers are irreducible with one node).

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for your precious comments. Only one point maybe I badly understood. To make sure that Leray-Serre specialises to the Leray-Hirsch theorem, I think we may need to ask the restriction map $H^*(X,\mathbb Q)\to H^*(F,\mathbb Q)$ to be surjective to make sure that $H^*(F,\mathbb Q)\to R\pi_*\mathbb Q$ is quasi-isomorphic, (so that we have that $H^*(X)=H^*(F)\otimes H^*(B)$. Please tell me if I said stupid things...

Comment: Oh that is true; that annoying surjectivity hypothesis does get in the way, particular for families of curves.